# Removing words from a string- Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Let's say I have a list **''Here Comes The Sun And I Say It Is Alright''**
and I need to remove every third word from the string and replace it with the previous one so the output will be **''Here Comes Comes Sun And And Say It It Alright''**. The teacher advised us to use **'%'**.. but I tried many different options like when (n%2!=0).. and it still didn't work.
It would be really nice if you'll help me :)

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: it's still without the part of the replacement.. the problem is that I can't even print the right words :(                                                                      val = "here comes the sun and i say it is alright"
val1=val.split()
n=len(val1)
i=0
while i<n:
 if i%2!=0:
  print val1[i]
 i=i+1

Comment: @MikhalAlkhazova , please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes I meant word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is what you need:

```
s = 'Here Comes The Sun And I Say It Is Alright'.split()

for i in range(2, len(s), 3):
    s[i] = s[i - 1]

print(' '.join(s)) # 'Here Comes Comes Sun And And Say It It Alright'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! but we still didn't learn the function join and we aren't allowed to use things we didn't learn.. maybe you have an idea how to resolve it with '%'?

Comment: @MikhalAlkhazova Do you know what `%` means in python?

Comment: yes it's divide that gives what is rest when you divide it.. that's why I tried to use it in my code but didn't succeed.

Comment: @MikhalAlkhazova: If "we aren't allowed to use things we didn't learn" you need to tell us what you have learned.

Comment: we've just learned if sentence, loops and lists.. some basic functions like sort, extend, range, pop, remove, append.

Comment: @MikhalAlkhazova I know what your teacher meant. But If you are not allowed to use `join()` then just use my solution and concatenate strings in a loop.

Comment: Can you maybe help me with that? Cause I need to make it okay for every input I'll do so I can't really us slice- s[0:1] and then to connect it.. because I'm not supposed to know the whole length of the string..

Comment: @MikhalAlkhazova Why you can't use slice (you mean `split()`?). Show us some code. If you want help we need to know how you get your input, how you store it (string or array) and what you are allowed to use.